# 2 ceiling roses required?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am trying to install long 10ft snooker table non-LED light in the garage.
The problem is it has two cables at each end (brown, blue, and  yellow/green).

The ceiling is insulated with kingspan and the other lights I have runs through trunking on outside (LED battons with 2-core).

So it looks like this long light needs 2 ceiling roses.

I fitted twin on/off switch when putting the other lights up because I knew at some point I would be getting the long light for the snooker table.

My questions are:

- What’s the best way to run new wires to both ends of this light?
- Can I join both ends then run a feed wire to the twin on/off switch?
- https://rosetta.org.uk/rosetta-brass-full-size-snooker-table-lighting-light-rail-bar-shade-choice-1707-p.asp
  [image]

Comment: Your location(country/region) will matter for answers.  Different countries, different rules.  You probably have a few different right ways to do it, plus some wrong ways.

Comment: Sorry I am in the Uk  Thanks

Comment: I took a crack at adding some formatting & spell check to that to make it readable. Please make sure it's still saying what you mean and that I haven't missed anything.

Comment: Photos would really help. It's hard to guess whether this is actually a snooker table light, or just a big fluorescent etc? Whether it's designed with a pass-through to the next in a series.

Comment: Their web site has a delightful 1990s vibe. Hopefully their inventory is more recent.

Answer (score 2):

I would just run 1 supply to a small junction box neatly fitted on the lamp and bring both wires to that.

The power required will be easily covered by one switched supply.

Comment: I wouldn't before looking at the lamp fixture itself. It might just be a pass-through to the next fitting, in which case you can just cap off one end & ignore it entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, so yesterday I done a test, I joined both ends with 3 core 1.5, and added a feed to one end wire used 3amp plug, put in the 6 screw in bulbs and it worked perfect, Today I’ll wire it in to 3 way light switch and split a feed to both ends. Thanks

Comment: Zooming in on the light image at the product link, it's rather apparent that there is only one set of wiring coming from the ceiling to the light (right hand chain in the image). The 2nd rose is only for mounting purposes. If one were to only mound the wired end of the light, the rest of it would end up on the snooker table and that might impact game play.

Comment: https://rosetta.org.uk/rosetta-brass-full-size-snooker-table-lighting-light-rail-bar-shade-choice-1707-p.asp
Thanks for replies again, I got it second hand and both ends have 3 core wires, so it must be connected to 2 roses, it also states on the web page 2 rose ceiling.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me, from the pictures and the web site, that **there is only one cable coming out of this fixture**, so the second ceiling rose is probably only a way for the second chain to be attached to the ceiling in a way that appears similar to the first one.  Otherwise you'd have to have some random mismatched hook there.

Hopefully your cable exits the ceiling exactly where you want one of these chains to go.  Otherwise you'll have *three* roses.